# Radius of convergence of power series*

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\sum_ {0}^{\infty}$ $a_n$$z^n$ be a convergent power series such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}$$\frac{a_n+1}{a_n}$$=R>0$.Let p be polynomial of degree d.Then the radius of convergence of power series $\sum_ {0}^{n}$ $p(n)a_n$$z^n$ equals

> > 1) $R$
> >
> > 2) $d$
> >
> > 3) $Rd$
> >
> > 4) $R+d$

Using some examples I find answer $3$.  Is it true. If not please give hint to solve this example.

Comment: I take p(n) as $n^2+n+1$.

Comment: $\lim_ {n\to \infty}$ $a_n+1/a_n$$=R$

Comment: No. It is $a_{n+1}/a_{n}$.

Comment: Could you give us other examples that you tried? Using only one example could lead you astray. And what have you tried other than specific examples?

Answer (score 3):

You’re interested in

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{p(n+1)a_{n+1}z^{n+1}}{p(n)a_nz^n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{p(n+1)}{p(n)}\right|\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right||z|=R|z|\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{p(n+1)}{p(n)}\right|\;,$$

since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=R>0$. Thus, you need to know

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{p(n+1)}{p(n)}\right|$$

when $p$ is a polynomial of degree $d$. If you’re not sure, write it out: let

$$p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_dx^d\;,$$

and compute

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_0+a_1(n+1)+\ldots+a_d(n+1)^d}{a_0+a_1n+\ldots+a_dn^d}\;.$$

HINT: Divide numerator and denominator by $n^d$.

However, it appears that none of the answers is right; one of them *would* be right if you were given that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=R$, or that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac1R$.